# How do I remove a disclosure chevron from a UITableViewCell (iOS5)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

Depending on user input, I need to remove the disclosure chevron from one of my table view's cells. In the controller's `viewDidAppear` method, I have the following code:

```
NSIndexPath *section0Row10 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:0];
[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:section0Row10] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
```

Nothing happens. I'd be grateful to know what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE:

These are static, grouped cells in a single section. I built the table view using the storyboard, and set each of the fields that I need to change programmatically, typically `UILabel`s, as named outlets by control-dragging from the table view into header file of the view controller.

For example, I have:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *symbolLabel;
```

in the .h file of my view controller. In the .m file, I include the following line in the `viewDidAppear` method:

```
self.symbolLabel.text = self.dataSource.symbol;
```

In this way, I haven't needed to implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` at all. Is this the incorrect way to do things?

Also: when the table view appears, the cell whose chevron I want to delete falls below the bottom of the screen.

Thanks for all your help and patience.

Comment: It's possible that your cell is not displyed at the moment when you call the method. In this case, cellForRowAtIndexPath: returns nil.

Comment: I didn't know this. The cell in question is indeed hidden when the method is called.

Answer (score 1):

When your cell is not displayed on the screen, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns `nil`. This is logical: cells are reused for saving memory, so the cells that don't have to be displayed are simply requeued so that they belong to an index path which is currently visible.

To solve this, instead of setting the cell's disclosure style explicitly from outside, set it in the

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

method. You can store the accessory type's numeric value or the condition upon whcich is based in e. g. in an NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the table. Or better , just that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading the cell:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:section0Row10] withAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this, but it seems to have had no effect. Also: `withAnimation:` should be `withRowAnimation:`

Comment: Oh, I've got it. I presume in your -cellForRow method, you are setting the cell's accessory view to show the chevron? If so, set a BOOL to yes when you need to remove the chevron, and have the -cellForRow method check this BOOL to see if the cell should display a chevron or not.

Comment: I'm sorry. I should've included more information. These are static cells whose contents I update programmatically by way of named outlets. I don't implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` at all. I'm getting the feeling that I should be doing things differently (?)

Comment: Generally the method has to be implemented when using a UITableView as it's one of the delegate/datasource methods. I don't quite understand how you're using the tableView if you're not using that method. Please can you update the question with some more information as to how you are using it and some code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call the reload function as mentioned by @max_

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:section0Row10] withAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

but when you call that, it is going to use your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in order to obtain a new cell to load. So you need to make sure that the cell returned from that method, for the index path specified in your reload method, does not have an `accessoryView`.

Maybe set a breakpoint in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and see what happens after the reload gets triggered.

Comment: No, these are not the problem. See our comments and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
{
NSIndexPath *section0Row10 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:0];
[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:section0Row10] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];`
}
```

With,

```
NSIndexPath *section0Row10 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:0];
[[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:section0Row10] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
```

You're not invoking your implementation of `CellForRowAtIndexPath:`.... That's the problem :)